# how can i get the selected item in tableview pyqt4

Tags: pyqt4, tableview, selecteditem

how can i get or print clicked item in a tableview?
here is sample code

```
def connectSlots(self): 
    # this does not work .. 
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.tableView, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked(const QModelIndex&"), self._onClick) 
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.tableView, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked(QModelIndex"), self._onClick) 

def _onClick(self, *args): 
    print "_onClick", args
```

Comment: I don't know if it's the cause of your problem, but your argument for SIGNAL should be `"clicked(QModelIndex)"` not `"clicked(QModelIndex")`.

Comment: yea i forgot closing parenthesis,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i found the answer :)

```
def connectSlots(self):
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.tableView, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked(QModelIndex)"), self.cellClicked)


def cellClicked( self, qmodelindex ):
    self.item = qmodelindex.data(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole).toString()
    print self.item
```

this will get and print the items that was clicked in the qtableview
just got hard time searching for examples

thx Stephen ..